# SQL query to find all rows with same timestamp + or - one second

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join

Row 3 in the following table is a duplicate. I know this because there is another row (row 5) that was created by the same user less than one second earlier.

```
row     record  created_by  created_dt
1       5734    '00E759CF'  '2020-06-05 19:59:36.610'
2       9856    '1E095CBA'  '2020-06-05 19:57:31.207'
3       4592    '1E095CBA'  '2020-06-05 19:54:41.930'
4       7454    '00E759CF'  '2020-06-05 19:54:41.840'
5       4126    '1E095CBA'  '2020-06-05 19:54:41.757'
```

I want a query that returns all rows created by the same user less than one second apart.

Like so:

```
row     record  created_by  created_dt
1       4592    '1E095CBA'  '2020-06-05 19:54:41.930'
2       4126    '1E095CBA'  '2020-06-05 19:54:41.757'
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.*
FROM table AS a1
    LEFT JOIN table AS a2
        ON a1.created_by = a2.created_by
            AND a1.created_dt > a2.created_dt
            AND a1.created_dt <= DATEADD(second, 1, a2.created_dt)
WHERE a1.created_dt IS NOT NULL
AND a.created_dt IS NOT NULL
```

This is what finally did the trick:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM table a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
        *
    FROM table a1
    WHERE a1.created_by = a.created_by
    AND ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a.created_dt, a1.created_dt)) < 1
    AND a.created_dt <> a1.created_dt)
ORDER BY created_dt DESC
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using. Is this SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists(
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where 
        t1.created_by = t.created_by 
        and abs(datediff(second, t.created_dt, t1.created_dt)) < 1
)
```

Comment: @j8d . . . This is better than an approach that uses `select distinct` because it does not require duplicate elimination.  It would be interesting to test the performance of this logic to the `lead()`/`lag()` approach if you have largish data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It was a modified version of your query that finally gave me what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.*
FROM @a1 AS a1
    LEFT JOIN @a1 AS a2 ON a1.[Created_By] = a2.[Created_By] 
        AND a1.[Record] <> a2.[Record]
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a1.[Created_Dt], a2.[Created_Dt])) < 1
```

Here is the sample query I used to verify the results.

```
DECLARE @a1 TABLE (
    [Record] INT,
    [Created_By] NVARCHAR(10),
    [Created_Dt] DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @a1 VALUES 
(5734, '00E759CF', '2020-06-05 19:59:36.610'),
(9856, '1E095CBA', '2020-06-05 19:57:31.207'),
(4592, '1E095CBA', '2020-06-05 19:54:41.930'),
(7454, '00E759CF', '2020-06-05 19:54:41.840'),
(4126, '1E095CBA', '2020-06-05 19:54:41.757')

SELECT DISTINCT a1.*
FROM @a1 AS a1
    LEFT JOIN @a1 AS a2 ON a1.[Created_By] = a2.[Created_By] 
        AND a1.[Record] <> a2.[Record]
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(SECOND, a1.[Created_Dt], a2.[Created_Dt])) < 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `lead()` and `lag()` instead of self-joins:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(created_dt) over (partition by created_dt) as prev_cd,
             lead(created_dt) over (partition by created_dt) as next_cd
      from t
     ) t
where created_dt < dateadd(second, 1, prev_created_dt) or
      created_dt > dateadd(second, -1, next_created_dt)
```